# How to unpack a dataframe of delayed dask objects?

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have used the `.map_partitions` with delayed functions and the result I got is a dataframe with delayed results in each row.

Is there any way to unpack those delayed objects?
Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very short answer: you should use `map_partitions` with a normal function, not a delayed one. The dataframe interface already provides laziness and parallelism, so you don't need to add another nested level.